# Bootstrap modal not showing in the expected way

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap and my modal won't show up the way it is supposed to, I have tried using the form that is inside the modal on the page, and there it shows up correctly but inside the modal, the form is also displayed as deformed, I have already tried solutions to similar questions here but they didn't work. The modal looks like this,
[image]

Expected to look something like this but without the footer:
[image]

The bootstrap code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div>
            <div class="styled-input wide">
              <input type="email" id="email" required />
              <label>Email</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="styled-input wide">
              <input type="number" id="phone" required />
              <label>Phone Number</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="styled-input wide">
              <input type="number" id="monthlyTurnOver" required />
              <label>Monthly Turnover</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="styled-input wide">
              <input type="text" id="purpose" value="B2B collection" required />
              <label>Purpose</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input class="enalo-small-btn" style="height: 2.4375rem; margin-bottom: .4rem;" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="contactUs()">
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check your css files? do you use any other css elements? 
Also post the code, thanks.

Comment: @Leo Sorry, I added the code now, this is all I am using

Comment: `<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">` is unclosed

Comment: I corrected that thank you, but it still isn't working

Comment: Your code isn't recreating anything

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what I did differently but I copied code from the modal I had built earlier on the same site which made it appear a lot better, than I overrode some styles and now it's visible properly, Thank you for your help,
The new code:

```
<div class="modal fade" style="font-size: 14px;" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
   aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog d-flex justify-content-center" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content px-2" style="max-width: 300px;"  id="modal">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <div class="ml-auto">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="crossclose" aria-label="Close" style="width: 83px;
                                       height: 50px;
                                       margin-top: 0px;
                                       border: none;">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
            </div>

         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container">
            <div>
              <div class="styled-input wide">
                <input placeholder="Email" type="email" id="email" required />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="styled-input wide">
                <input placeholder="Phone Number" type="number" id="phone" required />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="styled-input wide">
                <input placeholder="Monthly Turnover" type="number" id="monthlyTurnOver" required />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="styled-input wide">
                <input placeholder="Purpose" type="text" id="purpose" value="B2B collection" required />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
              <button class="enalo-small-btn" style="height: 2.4375rem; margin-bottom: .4rem;" type="submit" onclick="contactUs()">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: it won't help anyone ... you override bootstrap css with your custom css - there can be thousand reasons why modal do not display as you want

Comment: I overrode it later on, to change some styles for customization, before that when it wasn't showing properly none of the styles were being overwritten.